# making custom 404 page Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

I'd like to make a custom leaf page when I get 404 in Vapor 3.1.0. I've searched the web for it and even in the docs, I couldn't find out.
How could I do it?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I remember you should build your own middleware and catch 404 error there, and once 404 happens you should return leaf page instead of throwing it to next responder.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/brokenhandsio/leaf-error-middleware which provides a solution for doing what you want!

Basically it replaces the error middleware and loads up `404.leaf` or `serverError.leaf` for the different errors.